# DigitalOcean Network Firewall allowing SSH connections on ports other than only 22

Tags: security, ssh, digital-ocean, firewall, sshd

I have a droplet on DigitalOcean with IPv4 and IPv6 enabled. The droplet is behind a digital ocean network firewall with the following rules:

Inbound:

- SSH  TCP 22  All IPv4, All IPv6
- HTTP TCP 80  All IPv4, All IPv6
- HTTP TCP 443 All IPv4, All IPv6

Outbound:

- ICMP     ICMP                All IPv4 All IPv6
- All TCP  TCP     All ports   All IPv4 All IPv6
- All UDP  UDP     All ports   All IPv4

My understanding and expectation is that will block all ssh attempts on ports other than port 22. However when checking the sshd unit in systemd journal. I see the following entries:

```
2022-12-29 03:00:32 Disconnected from invalid user antonio 43.153.179.44 port 45614 [preauth]
2022-12-29 03:00:32 Received disconnect from 43.153.179.44 port 45614:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
2022-12-29 03:00:31 Invalid user antonio from 43.153.179.44 port 45614
2022-12-29 02:58:37 Disconnected from invalid user desliga 190.129.122.3 port 1199 [preauth]
2022-12-29 02:58:37 Received disconnect from 190.129.122.3 port 1199:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
2022-12-29 02:58:37 Invalid user desliga from 190.129.122.3 port 1199
```

and many more of these lines, which means the firewall is not blocking ssh connections on ports other than 22.

The following graph shows the number of ssh connections to ports other than 22 in the last hour. The connections are reduced with enabling the Network Filter, but they not diminished.

[image]

Could it be that the Network Firewall of DigitalOcean is broken?

What am I missing?

Anyone is seeing the same situation on their infrastructure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ports being shown in the log are the remote ports that the connections are coming from on the remote IPs, and not indicating that those ports are listening on your server or through the firewall. The firewall is configured from your description to allow for any remote IP and port to connect to your droplet on local ports 22, 80, and 443.

Comment: Ah... it's the port from which the connection was initiated... I misunderstood the log messages... thank you for clarifying this out!